# Play Framework - two assets controller in conf/routes file

Tags: playframework, playframework-2.4

I like to integrate links to external files (PDF documents) in an existing Play Framework 2.4 application. The application is only used in-house.

To avoid 'Action not found' messages, do I have to specify the path in the routes configuration file?

What I've done so far:

I have added the route - for the existing javascript files i already have an assets entry.

```
GET         /assets/plan/﻿*file    controllers.Assets.at(path="/home/entwickl", file)
GET         /assets/*file         controllers.Assets.at(path="/public", file)
```

Add unmanagedResourceDirectories in the build.sbt

```
unmanagedResourceDirectories in Assets += baseDirectory.value / "/home/entwickl"
```

And build the link in the html page

```
@if(sf.equalsIgnoreCase("S")) {
    <a href="@routes.Assets.at("plan/PO_675245.pdf")" />LINK</a>
} else            {
    @sf
}
```

Now I get an compilation error:

```
Compilation error not enough arguments for method at: (path: String, file: String)play.api.mvc.Call.
Unspecified value parameter file.

src="@routes.Assets.at("javascripts/login.js")"></script>
```

Probably the two routes cannot be clearly distinguished from each other. But how do I do that? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Check this [playframework doc](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.8.x/AssetsOverview#Reverse-routing-for-public-assets):

Try to change this:

```xml
@if(sf.equalsIgnoreCase("S")) {
    <a href="@routes.Assets.at("plan/PO_675245.pdf")" />LINK</a>
} else            {
    @sf
}
```

to something like this:

```xml
@if(sf.equalsIgnoreCase("S")) {
    <a href="@routes.Assets.at("/home/entwickl", "PO_675245.pdf")" />LINK</a>
} else            {
    @sf
}
```

Comment: In the meantime I have solved my problem with a new controller for displaying PDF documents. Not nice, but it works. I couldn't get it to work with two assets.

Thanks for your support.